# ReactJS Dynamic Anchor tag href rendering based on csv file Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, csv, dom

I'm using React and React-DOM inline to make a dynamic filter gallery for showcasing projects of my contributors.I have parsed a CSV file that contains the names of the different contributors, the category based on which the tiles will be sorted (project categories) and the URL to each project this is stored in `data` variable.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var photo = {
        id: i,
        category: data[i].Style,
        pageurl: "./explore/" + data[i].name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-") + ".html" ,
        //iu: "./explore/" + String(data[i].name) ,
        imageUrl: "./explore/" + String(data[i].image_path)
    };
    PHOTODATA.push(photo);

}
```

When I log this `PHOTODATA` variable the DOM shows the different URLs correctly as expected, like this.

```
0: {id: 0, category: "Futurism", pageurl: "./explore/steely-dan.html", imageUrl: "./explore/thumbnail.jpg"}
```

This is the piece of code where I render the `div` and the `<a>` tag using React

```
var Photo =  React.createClass({

render: function(){
return (
    <a className = "photo-container" href= {"./explore/"+ String(this.props.pageurl)} >
        <div  data-category={this.props.category} >
        
                <img src={this.props.imageUrl} />
        </div>
        </a>
       );
}
```

And this is how the rendered tag looks in the DOM.

```
<a class="photo-container" href="./explore/undefined.html" data-reactid=".0.1.$0"><div data-category="Futurism" data-reactid=".0.1.$0.0"><img src="./explore/thumbnail.jpg" data-reactid=".0.1.$0.0.0"></div></a>
```

I'm puzzled by how the URL comes out as `undefined` while when I try something like `{"https://www.google.com"}` then it renders it correctly. Only the dynamic rendering seems to have a problem. I've also tried changing the names of the variables but the issue still persists. Either the DOM doesn't render the `href` of it renders it as `undefined`.

How can I fix this issue to link each `divs` to their own custom `html` page defined by the CSV file?

Comment: how you get url in props as an object?

Comment: What do you mean? I created an array of objects containing the thumbnail, category, ID and its corresponding HTML URL and then called it using `this.props.url`

Comment: so it may be url is an array so why you calling array in href?

Comment: No, since each tile in my filter gallery corresponds to a different person, I constructed the url to be of the format `firstname-lastname.html` which can be seen in the first code snippet